# Additional parameters with MongoDB $sample

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've successfully used `db.collection('example').aggregate({$sample: {size: 1}})` in Node.js to retrieve a random sample from my collection, however, I'd like to put in an additional parameter to only sample an item from a certain subset.  I've tried adding an additional parameter (e.g., `db.collection('example').aggregate({sampleParam: {$gte: 1}}, {$sample: {size: 1}})`, which did not work.

I also understand that `.skip` could achieve this but that it is inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add a **`$match`** stage before using **`$sample`** like this:

```
db.collection('example').aggregate([
  {$match: 
      {sampleParam: {$gte: 1}}
  }, 
  {$sample: {size: 1}}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You query does not work aproply because `sampleParam` not is a `pipeline stage` you can try with so this:

```
{ "_id" : 11, "score" : 11, "name" : "ahn", "q1" : true, "q2" : true }
{ "_id" : 12, "score" : 12, "name" : "dane", "q1" : true, "q2" : true }
{ "_id" : 13, "score" : 13, "name" : "spec", "q1" : true, "q2" : true }
{ "_id" : 14, "score" : 14, "name" : "axe", "q1" : true, "q2" : true }
{ "_id" : 15, "score" : 15, "name" : "soplo", "q1" : true, "q2" : true }
{ "_id" : 16, "score" : 16, "name" : "tepe", "q1" : true, "q2" : true }
```

I guess that I have an user collections, so:

```
> db.user.aggregate([{$match:{score: {$gt:10}}}, {$sample:{size:1}}])
```

The query above return all `score` greater than 10 and show a simple document with `size`